# IdFTP performance issue when Parsing all the files in a directory and subdirectories

Tags: delphi, indy, ftp-client, indy10

I need to parse every single file in a directory including the files in sub directories and sub sub directories and ...
**I have already successfully done this using the code below :**

```
class function TATDFTPUtility.findAllDirectoryFiles(var ftpClient: TIdFTP; directory: String; deepness: Integer = 0): TidFTPListItems;
var
  I: Integer;
  localDirectoryListing: TIdFTPListItems;
  baseDirectory: string;
begin
  Result := TIdFTPListItems.Create;
  *// this function uses ftpClient.ChangeDirUp until it reaches the '' directory*
  changeUpToDirectory(ftpClient, '');
  try
    ftpClient.ChangeDir(directory);
    ftpClient.List;
    Result.Assign(ftpClient.DirectoryListing);
    localDirectoryListing := Result;
    baseDirectory := ftpClient.RetrieveCurrentDir;
    for I := 0 to localDirectoryListing.Count - 1 do
    begin
      if (localDirectoryListing.Items[i].ItemType = ditDirectory) then
      begin
        result := addTwoFTPListItems(result, findAllDirectoryFiles(ftpClient, baseDirectory + '/' + localDirectoryListing.Items[i].FileName));
      end;
    end;
  except
  end;
end;

class function TATDFTPUtility.addTwoFTPListItems(listA: TIdFTPListItems; listB: TIdFTPListItems): TidFTPListItems;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  Result := listA;
  for I := 0 to listB.Count - 1 do
  begin
    with Result.Add do
    begin
      Data := listB.Items[i].data;
      Size := listB.Items[i].Size;
      ModifiedDate := listB.Items[i].ModifiedDate;
      LocalFileName := listB.Items[i].LocalFileName;
      FileName := listB.Items[i].FileName;
      ItemType := listB.Items[i].ItemType;
      SizeAvail := listB.Items[i].SizeAvail;
      ModifiedAvail := listB.Items[i].ModifiedAvail;
      PermissionDisplay := listB.Items[i].PermissionDisplay;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Now the problem is that **this takes about 15-20 minutes !!!**
**Is there a more efficient way ?**
**Here is a few fact about this particular case :**
1- After i ran the program it found about 12000 files with almost 100-200 directories but the highest deepness was about 7
2- I only need to parse and i do not need to download or upload anything
3- The reason i have used an exception is because inside the FTP there are a few folder which i do not have access and this causes an `access violation` Error in `IdFTP` and i used `try...except` to ignore any directory which can not be accessed.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `ChangeDirUp()` (potentially many times?) and then calling `ChangeDir()` afterwards.  If `directory` is an absolute path, you can just call `ChangeDir()` one time to jump directly to the target folder and avoid `ChangeDirUp()` altogether.  The recursive loop inside of `findAllDirectoryFiles()` is using absolute paths from `RetrieveCurrentDir()`, so the repeated calls to `ChangeDirUp()` and `ChangeDir()` are wasted overhead.  You can greatly reduce overhead by not navigating up and down the folder tree unnecessarily.

`findAllDirectoryFiles()` is returning a newly allocated `TIdFTPListItems` that the caller must free.  That in itself is generally a bad design choice, but especially in this case because the recursive loop is not freeing those secondary `TIdFTPListItems` objects at all, so they are being leaked.

When adding files to the output `TIdFTPListItems`, you are only adding their filenames and not their paths.  What good is recursively searching for files if the caller does not know where each file was found?  Or do you only care about the filenames and not the paths?

You are ignoring the `deepness` parameter completely.

With that said, try something more like this instead:

```
class procedure TATDFTPUtility.findAllDirectoryFiles(ftpClient: TIdFTP; const directory: String;var files: TIdFTPListItems; deepness: Integer = -1);
var
  I: Integer;
  baseDirectory: string;
  subDirectories: TStringList;
  item: TIdFTPListItem;
  localDirectoryListing: TIdFTPListItems;
begin
  try
    if directory <> '' then
      ftpClient.ChangeDir(directory);
    ftpClient.List;
  except
    Exit;
  end;
  baseDirectory := ftpClient.RetrieveCurrentDir;
  localDirectoryListing := ftpClient.DirectoryListing;
  subDirectories := nil;
  try
    for I := 0 to localDirectoryListing.Count - 1 do
    begin
      case localDirectoryListing[i].ItemType of
        ditFile: begin
          item := files.Add;
          item.Assign(localDirectoryListing[i]);
          // if you need the full path of each file...
          item.FileName := baseDirectory + '/' + item.FileName;
        end;
        ditDirectory: begin
          item := localDirectoryListing[i];
          if ((item.FileName <> '.') and (item.FileName <> '..')) and
             ((deepness = -1) or (deepness > 0)) then
          begin
            if subDirectories = nil then
              subDirectories := TStringList.Create;
            subDirectories.Add(baseDirectory + '/' + item.FileName);
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
    if subDirectories <> nil then
    begin
      if (deepness > 0) then Dec(deepness);
      for I := 0 to subDirectories.Count - 1 do begin
        findAllDirectoryFiles(ftpClient, subDirectories[I], files, deepness);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    subDirectories.Free;
  end;
end;
```

When calling `findAllDirectoryFiles()` for the first time, you can set `directory` to either:

- a blank string to start searching in the current directory.
- a subfolder that is relative to the current directory.
- an absolute folder that is relative to the server's root.

And set `deepness` to either

- -1 for endless recursion
- >= 0 to specify how deep to recurse.

```
files := TIdFTPListItems.Create;
try
  TATDFTPUtility.findAllDirectoryFiles(ftpClient, 'desired directory', files, desired deepness);
  // use files as needed...
finally
  files.Free;
end;
```

Comment: thanks for you answer! i did not know i could use an absolute path and that i don't need to use `changeDirUp` ! and i had yet to implant the deepness which is why it wasn't doing anything, now back to you answer, i tried your code, there are a few problem, when you call the `findAllDirectoryFiles()` you are invaliding the `directoryListing` which is why i used an extra `FTPListItems` and assigned the value and i iterated on that, the second for must be `J` and most importantly there is a logical error too! the program runs for ever!!, i logged it and i noticed (read the next comment)

Comment: Your extra `TIdFTPListItems` object is unnecessary. And besides, your proposed change introduced a new memory leak, so I have removed that change. As for the original `DirectoryListing` being invalidated during the `subdirectories` loop, that is because I had that loop in the wrong place. I have fixed that now (making the extra `TIdFTPListItems` object copy unnecessary).

Comment: i noticed that the program runs forever! i logged it and saw that it loops back after going inside the folders and after finding the files, it comes out one layer and goes inside the same folders and looks at them again! and i think it simply loops at the 2 last layer infinitely, i will try to debug the function if i can.

Comment: Try the latest code. It should not be re-scanning previously-scanned folders (unless the server happens to be using virtual folders that redirect to folders higher up in the folder hierarchy. But unheard of, but not common, either).

Comment: i just ran your code, the previous problems are solved, my `logs` shows ` Parsed Files Count = 11587 Parsed Folders Count = 689` , which took 16 minutes ! it seems every 20 file takes about 1 second, is there a possibly faster approach ?

Comment: here is why i am in a need to parse all these files in the first place !, maybe you can come up with a better way, the people in this particular FTP server, upload files on a daily bases for about 30 client, each client has a different file ! all the files have a Date within their file name plus a certain keyword which blongs to their client here is an example of a file in the ftp server "the ftp address/Remy/RemyLebeau/2016/11/17/RL20161117.eau" the problem is that the path format is not always like this! sometimes they add extra folders in between for example "2016/11/hi!/17" !!(continue)

Comment: (this is from previous comment), and to make it worse even the date is not always like this ! sometimes its "016/11/17" !, anyway the point is i need to download the files in certain dates and i tried searching the folder with that date but because the pattern are so arbitrary i simply can not find a united pattern ! and i have to write a different pattern for each user !! the only stable thing is the file name format ! which is why i decided to parse all the files and filter them based on the date inside them and their extention (which shows which user it belongs to)

Comment: 20 files in 1 second = 50ms per file. That does not sound unreasonable for a parser. If you want to speed up the code, figure out a way to parse each file faster than 50ms, or parse multiple files in parallel (use multiple FTP connections processing different folder branches in separate threads), or parse fewer files overall. Maybe don't parse files you have already parsed, or maybe have the client publish somewhere you can monitor when a new file is uploaded, and then parse the file at that time. Parsing only 30 files a day is less overhead than parsing 11587 files at one time.

Comment: then 50ms per file is normal, i thought maybe i'm doing something wrong !  then one last thing, about the part where you said "figure out a way to parse each file faster" , can you give me some ideas ?, if i can double the speed it would be enough for my work!.

Comment: @aliahmadi before you can optimize for speed, you should profile your code to see where it is actually spending most of its time, then look for ways to reduce/remove any bottlenecks. Since you haven't show your parsing code, nobody here can help you with that. Consider posting it to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).